# When I press run, Python code has no input. How can I fix this?

Tags: python

this is my homework:

[image: ,]

And this is my code:

```
from math import gcd

class Rational:

   def __init__ (self, numerator, denominator):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator
        red = self.reduce()
        self.numerator = red.numerator
        self.denominator = red.denominator

   def add(self, other):
       self.numerator = self.numerator * other.denominator + other.numerator * self.denominator
       self.denominator = self.denominator * other.denominator
       
   def mul(self, other):
       self.numerator = self.numerator * other.numerator
       self.denominator = self.denominator * other.denominator

   def reduce(self):  
       if self.numerator == 0 : 
           return 0

       nd_gcd = gcd(self.denominator%self.numerator,self.numerator)
       if nd_gcd == 1:
          return self

       return Rational(int(self.numerator//nd_gcd), int(self.denominator//nd_gcd))
```

But when I click run, there is no output. I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have only declared the functions and the class. You are not instantiating it. So there will be no output.

Comment: @Soban I'm not that smart and I'm really bad at Python. How do I do that?

Comment: What output do you expect? Why do you expect output? Your task description does not say that it expects or should produce any output.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think the instructions say it should output the answer in reduced form for the fractions.

Comment: As far as I can tell (it is less-than-optimal to search through a picture instead of text) the instructions shown here do not say any such thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate your class. I also added an **str** function that lets you print your class:

```
from math import gcd

class Rational:

    def __init__ (self, numerator, denominator):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator
        red = self.reduce()
        self.numerator = red.numerator
        self.denominator = red.denominator

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.numerator) + "/" + str(self.denominator)
    
    def add(self, other):
        self.numerator = self.numerator * other.denominator + other.numerator * self.denominator
        self.denominator = self.denominator * other.denominator
       
    def mul(self, other):
        self.numerator = self.numerator * other.numerator
        self.denominator = self.denominator * other.denominator

    def reduce(self):  
        if self.numerator == 0 : 
            return 0

        nd_gcd = gcd(self.denominator%self.numerator,self.numerator)
       
        if nd_gcd == 1:
            return self

        return Rational(int(self.numerator//nd_gcd), int(self.denominator//nd_gcd))



a = Rational(2, 5)
b = Rational(2, 7)

a.add(b)
print(a)
```

You should also reduce after adding and multiplying.